# Laplace's equation in polar coords

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, polar-coordinates, harmonic-functions

Question: Suppose that the function u(r, $\phi$) satisfies Laplace’s equation for plane polar co-ordinates (r, $\phi$) i.e.

$$ ∇^2u = \frac{1}{r} \frac{∂}{∂r}(\frac{r∂u}{∂r}) + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{∂^2u}{∂\phi^2} = 0 $$

￼￼￼￼Writing u(r,$\phi$) = P(r)Q($\phi$), show that the most general solution that is a bounded solution in this region and that satisfies u(r, 0) = u(r, π/2) = 0 for all r > a is
$$
u(r,\phi) = \sum_{k=1}^∞ A_kr^{−2k} sin2k\phi.
$$

Hence find the unique solution in this region that satisfies the above conditions, $u(a, \phi) = u_0$ for $0<\phi<π/4$ and  $u(a,\phi)=−u_0$ for $π/4<\phi<π/2, $
where $u_0$ is a constant.

Now, I'm able to show the first part by going through the various steps and ending up with the general solution in the form

$$
u(r,\phi) = a_o + b_0lnr + \sum_{n=1}^∞ (A_nr^n + B_nr^{-n})(C_ncos(n\phi)+D_nsin(n\phi))
$$

After applying boundary conditions $u(r, 0) = 0$, I end up with $a_0 = b_0 = 0$ and $C_n = 0$ leaving

$$
u(r,\phi) = \sum_{n=1}^∞ (A_nr^n + B_nr^{-n})D_nsin(n\phi)
$$

Applying $u(r, π) = 0$, I find that $r^n\to\infty$ in the expansion, so therefore $A_n = 0$. Further, $sin(\frac{nπ}{2}) = 0$ when $ n = 2k$. Letting $A_k = B_k D_k$, we have
$$
u(r,\phi) = \sum_{k=1}^∞ A_kr^{-2k}sin(2k\phi)
$$

However, with the second part, i.e. finding the unique solution, would I be correct in finding $A_k$ separately for $ 0 < \phi < π/4 $ and $ π/4 < \phi < π/2 $ by using Fourier sine series, or would I be better off (still using Fourier) integrating from 0 to π/2? I'm also not quite sure what to use as f(x) when integrating.

Comment: There is probably a general theorem giving sufficient conditions for the uniqueness of a solution -- you might look for that instead for trying to compute the A's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
u\pars{a,\phi} = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}A_{k}a^{-2k}\sin\pars{2k\phi}
$$
$$
u_{0}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\sin\pars{2q\phi}\,\dd\phi
-
u_{0}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\sin\pars{2q\phi}\,\dd\phi
=
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}A_{k}a^{-2k}
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin\pars{2q\phi}\sin\pars{2k\phi}\,\dd\phi}
^{\ds{{1 \over 4}\,\pi\,\delta_{qk}}}
$$

> \begin{align}
> \\[3mm]
> &{1 \over 4}\,\pi A_{q}a^{-2q}
> =u_{0}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\sin\pars{2q\phi}\,\dd\phi
> -
> u_{0}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\sin\pars{2q\phi}\,\dd\phi
> \\[3mm]&=
> u_{0}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\sin\pars{2q\phi}\,\dd\phi
> -
> u_{0}\int_{-\pi/4}^{0}\sin\pars{2q\phi + q\pi}\,\dd\phi
> \\[3mm]&=
> u_{0}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\sin\pars{2q\phi}\,\dd\phi
> -
> u_{0}\pars{-1}^{q}\int_{-\pi/4}^{0}\sin\pars{2q\phi}\,\dd\phi
> =
> u_{0}\bracks{1 - \pars{-1}^{q}}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\sin\pars{2q\phi}\,\dd\phi
> \\[3mm]&=
> u_{0}\bracks{1 - \pars{-1}^{q}}{-\cos\pars{\pi q/2} + 1\over 2q}
> =u_{0}\,{1 - \pars{-1}^{q} \over q}\sin^{2}\pars{\pi q \over4}
> \end{align}

$A_{q}$ vanishes out for even $q$:
\begin{align}
{1 \over 4}\,\pi a^{-4k - 2}A_{2k + 1}
&=
{2u_{0} \over 2k + 1}\,\sin^{2}\pars{{\pi \over 4}\bracks{2k + 1}}
\\[3mm]&=
{2u_{0} \over 2k + 1}\,\bracks{%
\sin\pars{\pi k \over 2}\cos\pars{\pi \over 4}
+
\cos\pars{\pi k \over 2}\sin\pars{\pi \over 4}}^{2}
={u_{0} \over 2k + 1}
\\[3mm]
A_{2k + 1} & = {4u_{0}/\pi \over 2k + 1}\,a^{4k + 2}
\end{align}

> $$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
> u\pars{r,\phi}
> =
> {4u_{0} \over \pi}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over 2k + 1}\pars{a \over r}^{4k + 2}
> \sin\pars{2\bracks{2k + 1}\phi}}
> $$

Also
$$
u\pars{r,\phi}
=
-\,{4u_{0} \over \pi}\Im\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over 2k + 1}
\pars{{a \over r}\,\expo{-\ic\phi}}^{4k + 2}
=
-\,{4u_{0} \over \pi}\Im\fermi\pars{{a \over r\expo{\ic\phi}}}
$$
where $\fermi\pars{z} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}z^{4k + 2}/\pars{2k + 1}$. Then,
\begin{align}
\fermi'\pars{z} &= 2\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}z^{4k + 1}
=
2\,{z \over 1 - z^{4}} = {z \over z^{2} + 1} - {z \over z^{2} - 1}
\\
\Im\fermi\pars{z}&=\half\,\ln\pars{z^{2} + 1 \over z^{2} - 1}
=\half\,\Im\ln\pars{1 + z^{-2} \over 1 - z^{-2}}
=\half\,\Im\ln\pars{%
1 + \bracks{x + \ic y}^{2}/a^{2} \over 1 - \bracks{x + \ic y}^{2}/a^{2}}
\\[3mm]&=\half\,\Im\ln\pars{%
x^{2} - y^{2} + a^{2} + 2xy\ic \over -x^{2} + y^{2} + a^{2} - 2xy\ic}
\\[3mm]&=\half\,\Im\ln\pars{%
\bracks{x^{2} - y^{2} + a^{2} + 2xy\ic}\bracks{-x^{2} + y^{2} + a^{2} + 2xy\ic}}
\\[3mm]&=
\half\,\Im\ln\pars{%
-\bracks{x^{2} - y^{2}}^{2} + a^{4} - 4x^{2}y^{2} + 4a^{2}xy\ic}
\\[3mm]&=
\half\,\arctan\pars{%
4a^{2}xy \over -\bracks{x^{2} - y^{2}}^{2} + a^{4} - 4x^{2}y^{2}}
\end{align}

> In Cartesian coordinates:
> $$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
> u\pars{x,y}
> =-\,{2u_{0} \over \pi}\,\arctan\pars{%
> 4a^{2}xy \over -\bracks{x^{2} - y^{2}}^{2} + a^{4} - 4x^{2}y^{2}}}
> $$

$\large\tt\mbox{Please, check for some typo !!!}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Putting into cartesian coordinates was not required, but still interesting nonetheless!

Comment: @petite_montagne You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The functions

$$
  \sin 2\phi,\; \sin 4\phi,\; \sin 8\phi,\; \ldots,\; \sin 2n\phi,\;\ldots
$$
are the unique eigenfunctions of the $L^{2}[0,\pi/2]$ Sturm-Liouville problem
$$
       -\frac{d^{2}}{d\phi^{2}}f = \lambda f, \;\;\; f(0)=f(\pi/2) = 0.
$$
As such, these functions automatically form a complete orthogonal set of functions in $L^{2}[0,\pi/2]$. Because of this, you'll be able to satisfy an arbitrary condition at $r=a$:
$$
         \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}a^{-2n}\sin 2n\phi=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}u_{0} & 0 < \phi < \phi/4, \\ -u_{0} & \pi/4 < \phi < \pi/2\end{array}.\right.
$$
Furthermore, by orthogonality of these eigenfunctions on $[0,\pi/2]$,
$$
       A_{n}a^{-2n}\frac{\pi}{4} = A_{n}a^{-2n}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{2}2n\phi\,d\phi = u_{0}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\sin 2n\phi\,d\phi-u_{0}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\sin 2n\phi\,d\phi.
$$
In this case, the eigenvalues $\lambda=2^{2},4^{2},6^{2},\ldots$ of the Sturm-Liouville problem on $[0,\pi/2]$ dictates the powers $1/r^{2},1/r^{4},1/r^{6},\ldots$, as well as the orthogonal eigenfunction expansion. More explicitly, if
$$    
u(r,\phi) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}r^{2k}\sin 2k\phi,
$$
and $u(a, \phi)$ is known (as it is here) for $0\le \phi \le \pi/2$, then the automatic orthogonality of the eigenfunctions of the polar equation leads to
$$
    \int_{0}^{\pi/2}u(a,\phi)\sin 2n\phi d\phi = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}a^{2k}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin 2k\phi \sin 2n\phi d\phi = A_{n}a^{2n}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{2}2n\phi d\phi
$$
for all $n \ge 1$. The series at $r=a$ converges to the desired function except at $0,\pi/4,\pi/2$, where it converges to $0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't quite follow the last part in terms of finding a unique solution though.